# jQuery issue with .data() containing a space in its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

A lot of questions are similar to this, but I don't really see what I'm doing wrong.

So I pass open bootstrap modal that has below form:

```
    <form>
      VIN: <br>
      <input type="text" id="updateVin" name="updateVin" value="">
      <br>
      Description: <br>
      <input type="text" id="updateDescription" name="updateDescription" value="">
      <br>
      Color: <br>
      <input type="text" id="updateColor" name="updateColor" value="">
      <br>
      Model: <br>
      <input type="text" id="updateModel" name="updateModel" value="">
      <br>
      Area ID: <br>
      <input type="text" id="updateAreaId" name="updateAreaId" value="">
      <br>
      Geofence ID: <br>
      <input type="text" id="updateGeofenceId" name="updateGeofenceId" value="">
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" id="updateVehicle">Update</button>
      &nbsp;
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteVehicle"> 
      Delete 
      </button>
   </form>
```

I want to set the input values to be something different for different links to this same modal.

I accomplish this as such:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-UpdateModal", function () {
        var vin = $(this).data('vin');
        var description = $(this).data('description');
        var color = $(this).data('color');
        var model = $(this).data('model');
        var areaId = $(this).data('areaid');
        var geofenceId = $(this).data('geofenceid');
        $(".update #updateVin").val( vin );
        $(".update #updateDescription").val( description );
        $(".update #updateColor").val( color );
        $(".update #updateModel").val( model );
        $(".update #updateAreaId").val( areaId );
        $(".update #updateGeofenceId").val( geofenceId );
        $('h4.modal-title').text( 'Updating ' + vin + ':');
    });
```

I am getting the values from table data in one of my tables:

```
<td>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#my_modal" class="open-UpdateModal"
    data-deletevin=<%= vehicles[i].vin %>
    data-vin=<%= vehicles[i].vin %> 
    data-description=<%= vehicles[i].description %> 
    data-color=<%= vehicles[i].color %> 
    data-model=<%= vehicles[i].model %> 
    data-areaid=<%= vehicles[i].areaId %> 
    data-geofenceid=<%= vehicles[i].geofenceId %>>
    <%= vehicles[i].vin %> </a>
</td>
```

This works perfect! Other than the fact that if, for example, data-description is equal to 'Toyota Rav4', the input value will only be 'Toyota'. Other than that this works perfect.

Is this an issue with jQuery and whitespace? Or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried using $(this).attr('data-description') as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add quotes around the values:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#my_modal" class="open-UpdateModal"
data-deletevin="<%= vehicles[i].vin %>"
data-vin="<%= vehicles[i].vin %>"
data-description="<%= vehicles[i].description %>" 
data-color="<%= vehicles[i].color %>" 
data-model="<%= vehicles[i].model %>" 
data-areaid="<%= vehicles[i].areaId %>"
data-geofenceid="<%= vehicles[i].geofenceId %>">
<%= vehicles[i].vin %> </a>
```

Comment: yup...basic html...any space in attribute values demands quotes. Generally easier to always use them